# Wine games resolution/sound problems

Tags: sound, wine, games, resolution

First, the sound. It has never worked for me (in any game) I'm currently using wine version 1.3.25 (I'm pretty sure, is there a terminal command that checks that?). I've done some searching and tried some different things, but nothing has worked. Does anyone have any ideas (sorry for the lack of information, but I have no idea what to do)?

Resolution question moved to: [wine games resolution not working properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57176/wine-games-resolution-not-working-properly)

Comment: `wine --version` to get the version.

Comment: you may want to consider to split the sound and the graphics part into two separate questions to get better answers. Please also add exactly what you had already tried and what had failed so far.

Comment: Sound is broken in 1.3.25.  Downgrade to 1.3.24 to fix that.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It's just resolution then. Any ideas?

Comment: The two questions are now split.

Answer (score 1):

> Sound is broken in 1.3.25. Downgrade to 1.3.24 to fix that.

Thanks to @Kevin for the solution.