# Wine games resolution not working properly

Tags: wine, games, resolution

From: [Wine games resolution/sound problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56691/wine-games-resolution-sound-problems)

For some reason, in all the games I've tried (Battle Realms, Worms Armageddon, and StarCraft I), the resolution for the game is really small. I have virtual desktop enabled in the wine.cfg (resolution 1280x1024), but the game is displayed a lot smaller than the screen and is in the top left corner of the screen. In fact, it's pretty much exactly the same problem that someone had on appdb (except that my monitor is square, not wide screen): Don't Fullscreen, Opens Top-Left Hand Corner

I've done some reading on this, and I'm guessing (although not sure) that it has something to do with my xorg file not being able to handle anything other than 1280x1024 (if that is the case, though, I don't know what to do to add more resolutions).

Note: another thing that makes me think it has to do with my xorg is that when I play Worms Armageddon, the menu screen is small (like all the other games), but when I play a level, it goes to full-screen mode. Which, I'm guessing is because it supports 1280x1024 whereas Battle Realms/StarCraft (being older games and without recent updates) don't support that high of a resolution.

Note: another thing I noticed about playing StarCraft I, whenever I play it with virtual desktop less than 1280x1024 (i.e. windowed), instead of wine changing the StarCraft resolution to fit the window, StarCraft makes the window fit its resolution (which is really small).

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you use dual screen? If so look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/45042/force-full-screen-game-to-one-monitor/45053#45053

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is normal. In Windows and WINE, if a game requests a resolution it gets it. Change the game's resolution to something higher.

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks. But you know how Windows sets its resolution to match the game's resolution. Is there some way to do that with Wine/Ubuntu (so, if a game's resolution is 600x400, then Ubuntu changes its resolution to 600x400)?

Comment: @Wolf: Yeah, stop using a Virtual Desktop in WINE.

Comment: Wow, it worked, thanks (I was not expecting that)!

Comment: @Wolf: hehe... glad it worked :D